# How to upload a file in play framework?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework 2.0 and wanted to upload a file in my local file system. But I have no idea how to start this.can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3):

Our Form

```
@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    <input type="file" name="picture">
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
}
```

Our Upload action

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Text.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024)
public static Result upload() {
  MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
  FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
  if (picture != null) {
    String fileName = picture.getFilename();
    String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
    File file = picture.getFile();
    return ok("File uploaded");
  } else {
    flash("error", "Missing file");
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
  }
}
```

Just change the  `maxLength = 10 * 1024`(this is just around 10kb) to your desired length more of this can be found on the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaBodyParsers)

if you are gonna send the files via Ajax. use this

```
public static Result upload() {
  File file = request().body().asRaw().asFile();
  return ok("File uploaded");
}
```

The response from above will be encoded as `Mutlipart/form-data`  but will just contain the plain content files

Comment: thanks for posting...........i did this already but its gonna save in temporary folder.......what i wanted is to save in some destination folder.........

Comment: also the above code doesnt work for bigger files say 12gb......help is needed.......i would be very much thankful if u suggest me some links where i can read java in playframework.......

Comment: If I remember correctly, by default browsers cannot upload more than 4Gb at max. That's something you should consider. however if you are able to bypass your way around it, you can configure your Play configuration to accept files within certain size.  I updated my answer.

With regards to sending to another destination. You already have the file named file, why don't you just transfer it programmaticaly

Comment: thanks for answering,now  i am able to get it copied to the specified destination but it works only for small files.even though if i add the line (what u said) in the configuration file doesnot have any effect......

Comment: Are you using Play for Scala developers? or Play for Java developers?

Comment: play for java developers

Comment: thanks dude but as you mentioned the browser doesn't allow me to upload the file of size greater than 4 GB ,so adding the above statement doesn't help me. I explored on this and i think that i need a code that split my file into several small files before uploading it and after its done a function or a code should merge this small files into one single.so any suggestions dude

Comment: I think you should ask that in another question. Things are getting way off topic

Comment: okay  dude but what about the maxlength, i included the maxlength line in my code  as you mentioned but it doesn't help me...

Comment: Which file and directory does the '@BodyParser.Of' belong in?