# How to upload a file larger than 4GB in play framework?

Tags: playframework

I am trying to upload a file to a destination folder ,it work well for file less than 2 GB but when i try to upload a file oh 11 GB it fail any suggestions.

Comment: Please give us a bit more information. What do you mean by "it fail [sic]"? Any exceptions or error messages? Is the limit 2 or 4 GB? What OS are you on? 32 or 64 bit? What filesystem are you writing to? Are you running a 32 or 64 bit JVM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload a file in play framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025930/how-to-upload-a-file-in-play-framework)

Comment: actually in my application i am trying to upload a file whose size is greater than 12 GB.when i upload a file of size 50kb or more ,its getting successfully uploaded but if i try to upload the file of size 12 GB then i am getting an error, i explored on this and i think i need a function that split my file into several small files and then upload it ...any suggestion guys, how  can i achieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to upload a huge file in play framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076771/how-to-upload-a-huge-file-in-play-framework)

Answer (score 0):

All browsers have a limit on the size of a file that can be uploaded. You have to use a javascript library that splits ands the file in multiple chunks, like [resumable.js](http://resumablejs.com/).

You might want to check this [sample application](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/play-java-resumable) we did to fix a similar problem we had.