# how to upload a huge file in play framework?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In my application i am trying to upload a file to the destination folder, the browser doesn't allow me to upload the file of size greater than 4 GB and my file size is 15 GB.I am struck here and have no idea how to upload it.Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 18):

You can solve this problem in two stage:

1. You need to split huge file into smaller chunks and then send them to the server. To achieve this you may use some `javascript` libraries, for example `Resumable.js`
2. In your play2 controller you need to assemble these chunks using `Iteratee` API and then your can do what ever you want with your file.

**EDIT:**

Let's use `resumable.js` as example for the client side, I will not dive into the details, you can find a documentation and the examples [here](https://github.com/23/resumable.js)

Our view will be minimalist(only link to select a file or files) :

```html
@()
@main("File upload"){
    <a href="#" id="browseButton">Select files</a>
}
```

Our javasctipt :

```js
$(function(){
  var r = new Resumable({
    target:'/test/upload'
  });

  r.assignBrowse(document.getElementById('browseButton'));

  r.on('fileSuccess', function(file){
    console.debug(file);
  });
  r.on('fileProgress', function(file){
    console.debug(file);
  });
  // more events, look API docs
});
```

Our main.scala.html :

```html
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/style.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        @*We include resumable.js library*@
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/resumable.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        @*Our javascript for file upload*@
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/upload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

And our server side, in play controller :

First we need to create a function that will treat our file part by consuming our chanks and producing the result - Array[Byte] in our example.

```scala
 // hadle file part as Array[Byte]
  def handleFilePartAsByteArray: PartHandler[FilePart[Array[Byte]]] =
    handleFilePart {
      case FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
        // simply write the data to the a ByteArrayOutputStream
        Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], ByteArrayOutputStream](
          new ByteArrayOutputStream()) { (os, data) =>
          os.write(data)
          os
        }.mapDone { os =>
          os.close()
          os.toByteArray
        }
```

then we can define a custom body parser:

```scala
// custom body parser to handle file part as Array[Byte]
  def multipartFormDataAsBytes:BodyParser[MultipartFormData[Array[Byte]]] =
    multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsByteArray)
```

and in the end our controller may looks like:

```scala
def handleFileUpload = Action(multipartFormDataAsBytes){ request =>
 // retrieve file name from data part   
 val fileName  = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("resumableFilename").get.headOption
 // retrieve arrays of byte from file part and write them to file
    request.body.files foreach{
      case FilePart(key,filename,content,bytes)=>
        import scalax.io._
        val output:Output = Resource.fromFile(fileName.getOrElse("default"))
        output.write(bytes)
    }
    Ok("")
  }
```

List of imports for the controller :

```scala
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse.Multipart._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse._
import play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse.Multipart.FileInfo
import play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.FilePart
```

Comment: thanks a lot for posting the answer, actually i am new to javascript and play so could you please give some idea on how to implement it?

Comment: I am on play 2.4.4 and looks like some of the API changed a lot. Any chance you can update the answer to more recent version? In particular, I am strugling with: handleFilePart