# uploading a 15 Gb file and downloading it in playframework for java.is it possible?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to upload  a  file of size 15 Gb in play framework for java , but getting error because the browser doesn't allow it?any help is highly appreciable

Comment: 15GB is toooo large for a web transaction! Isn't it possible to change the scenario? for example asking user to split the file and upload them individually

Comment: thanks dude but can i have a code that split the file submitted by the user without asking it and when we submit the upload button ,all the split files get uploaded at the specified destination and we have a code to merge it into so that at the specified destination we have a single file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload a file larger than 4GB in play framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043616/how-to-upload-a-file-larger-than-4gb-in-play-framework)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to upload a huge file in play framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076771/how-to-upload-a-huge-file-in-play-framework)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in HTTP that prevents you from uploading 15GB files, or 15TB files for that matter.  In theory, there's no maximum size of file Play can handle if chunked transfer encoding is used and the underlying filesystem can handle it.  For unchunked requests, the theoretical maximum would be 2 ^ 63 bytes (8192 petabytes), since the underlying webserver - Netty - uses `long` to handle the Content-Length header.

However, some web browsers use signed/unsigned 32 bit integers to manage content lengths, which put them at a maximum of 2GB or 4GB.  Neither Google Chrome, nor Opera, have this limitation, so if your user wants to upload a 15GB file, they should use Google Chrome or Opera.

Play can handle 15GB uploads, though I would strongly advise setting `scalaVersion := "2.10.3"` in your `Build.scala`, there was a memory issue with earlier versions of Scala and iteratees.

By default, Play will save `multipart/form-data` body parts to a temporary files.  In Scala, you can change this to stream directly to a database or something similar, by supplying a custom PartHandler.  See here for more documentation:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFileUpload

Comment: thanks for posting the answer but i tried a lot but unable to upload a file of size more than 2GB from mozilla ,my RAM is 4GB.....help is really nedded

Answer (score 1):

Uploading very large data to a web server is not possible due to browser limitation on HTTP request time. So you have to split your data into smaller chunks. If you want to make this process transparent to user, you have to use some third party technologies like Microsoft `SilverLight`. I had such experience before.

You can implement a hidden `SilverLight` component (without any GUI) that its main responsibility would be to read a file, split it into smaller parts and upload them to server transparently. You can call its functions through JavaScript. This way you can also filter file type (by extension) and also let the user to select multiple files at the same time. The component will split the file to desired sizes, upload them individually to server and acknowledge the host page (by calling a `JavaScript` callback) about the end of the process. You can then submit your main form (or send the original AJAX request) through host page and access uploaded files on server side.

You can temporarily save file parts on your server and return a ticket to the `SilverLight` component which passes it to the host page in order to find uploaded files on server.

Another solution is to use FileAPI in HTML5. It's not supported by all browsers, but as you are trying to do this only on your local computer, you can install the required version of the browers. There is a slicing feature in this API which let you read part of a large file in memory. In your case, you can read the file using this feature and send each part individually. Take a look at this link:

[Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: actually i am not uploading it to server.I am uploading it to my local machine so any idea about how can i split the file using javascript.

Comment: You can't access file system API in `JavaScript`. The only way was `FileSystemObject` ActiveX in IE. It let you access file system through an ActiveX. So you can read a file, manipulate the contents and (in your case) split the contents to send them to the server side. But from IE8, it seems that there is some restriction on using it. More information available [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/27092b49-7d3e-4d86-9ffb-223a26037c3f/new-activexobjectscriptingfilesystemobject-failing-in-ie8)

Comment: i am getting confused, actually i am new to play framework and have never worked on this all so please tell me how can i split my file into different files before uploading.help is really needed

Comment: It's completely a client side concern and it doesn't matter what is your server side technology. Actually you have to solve it in client side and the only solution is to access the file system and the only file system api is `FileSystemObject` ActiveX in IE. Other browsers has no such mechanism (as far as I know) to access file system. Do you have any experience in JavaScript?

Comment: Take a look at this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx). It let you know how to read/write to a file through this ActiveX

Comment: thanks a lot for keep posting the answers , i read on how to read/write a file through this ActiveX but no information was provided on splitting the file.......please help sir

Comment: I've updated the document. Another solution base on HTML5 is also possible. Take a look at the link in my answer