# How to upload files on a website built using Play framework?

Tags: file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play framework. I am building a web app. In one of the pages user is allowed to upload files. I have no idea how to implement this. I also want that when a new file is uploaded it should be stored in a new folder which is dynamically named using the upload id.

How can I implement these features?

Comment: Have you read the official documentation? There is a whole section on file uploading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload a file in play framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025930/how-to-upload-a-file-in-play-framework)

Comment: What sort of file ? any ?

Comment: (As well as a duplicate, this can be put on hold as too broad).

Answer (score 0):

Read here for Java Playframework:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFileUpload

And here for Scala Playframework: 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFileUpload